# How to Sort Data Table without resetting its Column Properties?

Tags: vb.net

I am Trying to use this way,but `ToTable()` method resetting table Column Properties like....(Expression of the column  becomes empty String).Can Anyone help me in this.

Thank you.

```
Dim dataView As New DataView(table)
dataView.Sort = " AutoID DESC, Name DESC"
Dim dataTable AS DataTable = dataView.ToTable()
```

Comment: Normally, you can have multiple views over the same data; assuming you're using data-binding here, why not just use the *view* as the data source here? Meaning: is there an actual reason you want to end up with a `DataTable` here rather than a `DataView`? (also, I hate to keep saying it, but: `DataTable` is *essentially* a legacy API; it works, and it'll keep working, but it isn't going to make your life easy compared to say a `List<T>` for some POCO `T`, which *tends* (subjective) to be the preferred option these days)

Comment: You don't need all this. Just use the `table.DefaultView.Sort` or `table.DefaultView.RowFilter` properties. You don't need to re-set the DataSource. The DataTable object implements all the method needed to notify bound controls of changes in the DataSource. Use a BindingSource to further *spread the news*.

Comment: There's no need to sort the `DataTable`. If you actually do want the data in the `DataTable` sorted then you should have included the appropriate `ORDER BY` clause in your query. Once the `DataTable` is populated, sorting it is not only not possible but also pointless. Just bind the `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and bind that to your control(s). The `Sort` property of the `BindingSource` will sort the displayed data. If you're not binding, just set the `DefaultView.Sort` and then access the data via the `DefaultView` instead of the `Rows` collection.

Answer (score -1):

What may be missing is assigning  DefaultView of data table to DataView.
Can you please try below codes  :-

```vb
Dim dataView As New DataView(table) 
dataView =table.DefaultView
dataView.Sort = " AutoID DESC, Name DESC" 
Dim dataTable AS DataTable = dataView.ToTable()
```

let me know the results whether it resolved your issue or not

Comment: Hi Dhiraj , I tried this but Same problem Column expression becomes empty

Comment: If i use DataView.Totable() problem arriving

Answer (score -1):

The only way to work with sorted data is by working with DataView. Views are meant to be a projection of your table with custom display logic (similar to views in SQL)

Apply the Sorting logic on table.DefaultView and then iterate over each row

C# Code :

```
table.DefaultView.Sort = " Column1 ASC, Column2 DESC";
DataView dv = table.DefaultView;

foreach(DataRowView drv in dv)
{
     DataRow dr = drv.Row;
  // Your logic goes here
}
```

In case you don't wish to iterate, you can simply return the instance of DataView to the calling function.

### Edit

Correct code:

```
table.DefaultView.Sort = "Column1 ASC, Column2 DESC"

For Each drv As DataRowView In table.DefaultView
    'Use drv here.
Next
```

A `DataRowView` can be used pretty much the same as you would usually use a `DataRow`, although there are differences.

Comment: That code is wrong for a number of reasons. It's C# rather than VB, for a start. You're treating `Sort` like a function that returns a `DataView` rather than a `String` property. A `DataView` has no `Rows` property. The `DataView` itself is the list but it contains `DataRowView` objects, not `DataRow` objects. I have provided the correct code.

Comment: Thanks jmcilhinney ! Idea was to apply sorting logic on the defaultview itself rather than going for a new DataView instance

Comment: Sure, but a good answer needs to be much more than a general idea and then a grossly incorrect implementation. Showing people how to do something the wrong way is not an answer to a question.

Comment: True, will be more careful in future. Thanks !

Comment: The question i asked because to know the alternate approach to sort the Data table but As per all responses ,i got to know that Only way is by working with Dataview and i followed this approach and  sorting is working  fine for me but   the core issue  is still exist that why Column Property is resetting .As I mentioned above if I use Dataview.Totable() it is resetting Column Properties.for Ex (Column Expression becomes Empty).The only concern is that y dataview.Totable() resetting and If i use Dataview.Table ,my problem will get solve but due to Some Bussiness constraint i can not use it .